# is there any way to handle continuous updates in firebase array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Flutter app where i am listening continuously to a BLE device which broadcasts data when there is any change in the pressure of a tyre. It is a tyre pressure monitoring system.

when a user starts a new ride I create a document of that ride and start listening to the pressure sensor on BLE.Whenever it broadcasts a new value i concatenate it into the `rideData` array.
and its working fine.

The issue arises when i want to stop a ride i will write an endTime to that same document and it ends. but it takes a while until it publishes all the previous values to fire store these values are very frequent and it keeps on pushing it. so Ending a ride seems like wait in the line for its turn and then after some time it ends the ride .

It should happen instantly,
I tried to create a state and checked that a ride data will pushed only if the state is false, on click of ending a ride button i sat that state but takes time even then.

[image: Image of firebase table]

Here my code that push data on the firebase.

```
void deviceData(firstDevice, secondDevice) async {
LocationData _locationData;
_locationData = await location.getLocation();
var firstDeviceData = parseManufacturerData(firstDevice);
var secondDeviceData = parseManufacturerData(secondDevice);
if (mounted) {
  print("mounted is $mounted");
  setState(() {
    frontPressure = (firstDeviceData["pressure"]);
    frontTemperature = (firstDeviceData["temperature"]);
    rearPressure = (secondDeviceData["pressure"]);
    rearTemperature = (secondDeviceData["temperature"]);
  });
}

var newData = {
  "lat": _locationData.latitude,
  "long": _locationData.longitude,
  "time": new DateTime.now(),
  "front": firstDeviceData,
  "rear": secondDeviceData
};
if (!isEnding) {
  auth.currentUser().then((value) async {
    if (value != null) {
      if (value.uid != null) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("userCurrentRides")
            .where('user', isEqualTo: value.uid)
            .where('isActive', isEqualTo: true)
            .snapshots()
            .first
            .then((event) {
          event.documents.first.data;
          if (event.documents.length > 0) {
            print(newData);
            String docId = event.documents.first.documentID;
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('userCurrentRides')
                .document(docId)
                .updateData(
              {
                "rideData": FieldValue.arrayUnion([newData])
              },
            ).then((value) {
              print('new update');
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  }
 }
```

To stoping ride i am using following function

```
void stopRide(context) {
    setState(() {
      isEnding = true;
      frontPressure = "0.0";
      frontTemperature = "0.0";
      rearPressure = "0.0";
      rearTemperature = "0.0";
    });
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
    if (currentSubscription != null) {
      currentSubscription.cancel();
    }
    auth.currentUser().then((value) async {
      if (value != null) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("userCurrentRides")
            .where('user', isEqualTo: value.uid)
            .where('isActive', isEqualTo: true)
            .snapshots()
            .first
            .then((currentRideSnapshot) {
          var local = currentRideSnapshot.documents.first.data;
          local["endTime"] = new DateTime.now();

          String docId = currentRideSnapshot.documents.first.documentID;
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('userCurrentRides')
              .document(docId)
              .setData({"endTime": new DateTime.now(), "isActive": false},
                  merge: true).then((value2) {
            Firestore.instance
                .collection("userCurrentRides")
                .where('user', isEqualTo: value.uid)
                .snapshots()
                .first
                .then((currentRideSnapshot) {
              _progressHUD.state.dismiss();
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: How often are is the `deviceData()` method executed? It's not very optimized for frequent use (several times per second)

Comment: it depends on the frequency of broadcast from the device, some times may be 10 times per second